# Fetching particular count of images from folder

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this code to fetch images and display them in `pictureboxes` of particular child form ,same thing I am going to do for  4 5 more child forms ,but I don't want these images to get repeated in any of the forms or picture boxes,how can i do that ? and on each form I have 3 `pictureboxes`

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        string LoginName;
        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes;
        List<String> filesToShow = new List<String>();
        public MainForm(string lognName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.LoginName = lognName;
            pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox> {
                pictureBox1,
                pictureBox2,
                pictureBox3
            };
            ShowImages();
        }
        private List<String> GetFilesToShow()
        {
            String str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string path = str + "\\Image\\";
            return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        }
        private void ShowImages()
        {
            List<int> selectedImages = new List<int>();
            foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxes)
            {
                if (filesToShow != null && !filesToShow.Any())
                {
                    filesToShow = GetFilesToShow();
                }

                if (filesToShow != null && filesToShow.Any()) // If any files then allow the code to delete the shown images
                {
                    if (filesToShow.Count >= pictureBoxes.Count)
                    {
                        filesToShow.Reverse();
                        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            pictureBox.ImageLocation = filesToShow[i];
                        }                        
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a global list of all files names of all pictures present (say in session variable) and in a page when you are going to add an image to a picture box, remove it from the global list, so in this way in the other pages it won't get repeated.

Something like this

```
Session["filenames"] = GetFilesToShow();
```

Comment: but where should I have that global list ,I mean this all are the child forms in which I am gonna display images so how and where should  I add this ,I mean in parent form or child form ,If i remove it from one child form how that will get reflected in another child form ,can u please show ,

Comment: @Durga - you can place the code in the child pages and check is the session key is null or not before adding the file names

Comment: but how those removed items will get reflected in  another child pages